# Webstorm 11 shows compile-time typescript error for valid code

Tags: typescript, webstorm, compile-time

Using WebStorm 11.0.3, Typescript ver 1.8.9

In file: ./platform/browser/index:

```
export * from './directives';
export * from './pipes';
export * from './providers';
```

In file directives.ts (and same in pipes.ts and provider.ts):

```
... 
export const DIRECTIVES = [
  provide(PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES, {useValue: APPLICATION_DIRECTIVES, multi: true})];
```

In file main.ts, the following call is made:

```
import { DIRECTIVES, PROVIDERS, PIPES } from './platform/browser';
```

- red squigglies now show under each: DIRECTIVES, PROVIDES and PIPES

This seems to be is valid code (and it runs fine) and should not show as a compile-time validate import error.

Any suggestions?  Thanks.

Comment: could you please try WS 2016.1 ?

Comment: is that a beta version?  Webstorm claims that 11.0.3 is the current version and that's what I'm using.

Comment: no, it isn't. It is a new release version. http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2016/03/webstorm-2016-1-1/

Answer (score 0):

Webstorm 11 has problems with angular2 it is not fully compatible. but in webstrom 2016 has lot of these issues are fixed